# in Symfony, Frontend App, Using one of Module's form on another Module

Tags: symfony1, module, captcha, symfony-forms

I am building a project with Symfony. Its blog-like web site. I need to implement:
Writing comment for every article. Every comment must be moderationed by editors etc.

Everything is ready. I have a backend, use group, perms. so on. Just i need to comment form on article's show page.

My question is can i use my comment module's newSuccess temp. If yes, how? When i copy and paste the content of newSuccess, its not working evenif some conf.

Do you know there is way to use comment module's form at article module? and how can i configure it?

Thanks for spend your time to read -maybe to answer (;-

Comment: what about the validation of the comment form embedded in the article? when failed the validation, will it redirect back to the article page listing all the errors? Or jump to the comment view? and what about after adding the comment successfully, will it come back to the article page pointing to the comment saying your comment has been added successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the form in your controller:

```
public function executeShowArticle(sfWebRequest $request)
{

  // assume weve already retrieved and set $this->article
  $comment = new Comment();
  $comment->setArticle($this->article);
  $this->commentForm = new CommentForm($comment);

}
```

then you can use `echo $commentForm` in the template for your article. If you are customizing the layout of the comment form then move that form to a partial and do `include_partial('comment/form', array('form' => $commentForm);` from your article view. alternatively you could make a componet instead of using a straight partial... something like:

```
// in commentComponents.class.php
public function executeArticleCommentForm()
{
   $comment = new Comment();
   $comment->setArticle($this->article);
   $this->form = new CommentForm($comment);
}

// in article/showArticleSuccess.php
<?php include_component('comment', 'articleCommentForm', array('article' => $article)); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it helps me a lot to understand partial and component